# How to change the size of an icon in an ion-header-bar?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionicons

I'm using ionic version `1.2.4`.

I'm essentially trying to reduce the size of the icon by changing it's font size. What would be the appropriate CSS selector to change the `font-size` of the icon in the code below? Nothing I try seems to be working.

```
  <ion-nav-bar>
    <ion-nav-buttons side="right">
        <button class="button button-clear">
            <i class="icon ion-edit"></i>
        </button>
    </ion-nav-buttons>
  </ion-nav-bar>
```

Comment: You can add custom class for style and give it style.

Comment: I've tried that. No luck.

Comment: Did you give that `!important` ?

Comment: can you create fiddle or plnkr ? will take a look

Answer (score 1):

Declare your button like this

```
<button class="button button-icon icon ion-android-notifications"></button>
```

Add this class to your project css file.

```
.bar .button.button-icon:before {
    font-size: 40px;
}
```

Comment: Please try this: `.bar .button.button-clear .icon:before { font-size: 40px}` for the button declared in your question.

Comment: Can you debug the html code in developer console and see if you have `::before` within the `<i>` markup. If its there, select it and try `font-size` in the Styles pane.

Comment: There is an `::after` within the `<i>` tag. I've tried this, no luck... :/

Comment: [Please check this](http://play.ionic.io/app/606268f48a6b). There is a `::before` within the `<i>` tag and not `::after`. I used your version 1.2.4 version.

Comment: Sorry, finally this works. The error was actually how I was writing the selector in LESS. I was using the wrong pseudo selector syntax and correcting that fixed the issue...